# Why K-Cross validation need to fit first?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I get an error in the following code unless I do a fit on the SVC:

> This SVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate
>   arguments before using this method.

Unless I do this:

```
 clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Why I need to do a fit before doing a cross validation?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

iris = datasets.load_iris()

# Split the iris data into train/test data sets with 40% reserved for testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target,
                                                                     test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

# Build an SVC model for predicting iris classifications using training data
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)

# Now measure its performance with the test data
clf.score(X_test, y_test)   

# We give cross_val_score a model, the entire data set and its "real" values, and the number of folds:
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Your cross_val_score runs fine without the fit.

You do need to fit before running score.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing that error is because you are asking your estimator (`clf`) to compute the accuracy of its classifications (with the `clf.score` method) before it actually knows *how* to do the classification. To teach `clf` how to do the classification you have to train it by calling the `fit` method. This is what the error message is trying to tell you.

`score` in the above sense has nothing to do with cross-validation, only accuracy. The `cross_val_score` helper method you use can take an *untrained* estimator and compute a cross-validated score for you data. This helper trains the estimator for you and that's why you don't have to call `fit` before using this helper.

See the [documentation for cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) for more information.